# how to add back button on action bar

Tags: android, webview, android-actionbar

my app has two simple page activity and i want to know how add action bar in my application with back button

thank u in advanced ....

my code is....

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web1);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://dcs-dof.gujarat.gov.in/live-info.htm");
//        web.getProgress();


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.add(0,1,menu.NONE,"About");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"About",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,about.class);
            startActivity(i);

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your application's target is >= `API LEVEL 11`, you can use the native `ActionBar`, otherwise you have to use `SherlockActionBar`. To display the "back button", in the first case:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

in the second case

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

As mentioned from `@rudys`, another solution could be to use appcompat shipped with the version 7 of the support library. You can take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), in oder to get more information.

Comment: I would like to suggest AppCompat ActionBar rather than ActionBarSherlock, as ABS may not be developed anymore.

Comment: i have one manu item when menu item open and then i want to back to home with use of action bar so how can i implement...?

Comment: my menu item code is given------>                                                                           public class about extends Activity
{

    private TextView tv;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about_main);

        ActionBar ab=getActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }